# Slow SSH connections to hairpin NAT

Tags: networking, router, ssh

I have an http and ssh server in my LAN behind a residential router. The router is configured to forward TCP and UDP ports in the range 1:1024 from the public interface (1.2.3.4) to the server inside the lan (192.168.0.12). 
I can reach the server on the public IP address both from the internet and from inside the LAN.

The problem is that SSH connections from a client in the LAN to the *public* IP of the router are extremely slow (~10 fold reduction) compared to connections from a client in the LAN to the *private* IP of the server. This is not the case for HTTP connections.

Some reduction in speed when using the public IP is expected because of the overhead of doing NAT, but I'd expect this to be independent of the protocol.

**Some examples**

This downloads at ~3MB/s with frequent stalling:

```
tleonardi@host ~ $ scp 1.2.3.4:/path/to/file.txt .
```

While this downloads at ~30MB/s:

```
tleonardi@host ~ $ scp 192.168.0.12:/path/to/file.txt .
```

Downloading the same file over HTTP on the public IP is only ~2MB/s slower than the private IP.

**Further information**

- The ssh server is configured with `UseDNS no`
- Running Wireshark during the file transfer from 1.2.3.4 (the slow one) revealed numerous packets marked as TCP Dup Ack
- The router's MTU is set to 1500
- In addition to scp also ssh connections to a remote terminal suffer frequent freezes.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is the connect to the server appearing with the router's IP address.  If not you likely have asymmetric routing occurring.  Packets from the client go to the router are the destination address is translated.  Because the source address is local, your client sees and gets packets directly from the router.  The router may also see the responses and send them back to the client.  This would explain the duplicate packets.  The client's IP stack is likely very busy dealing with the duplicated packets.

When doing hairpin NAT you usually need translate both the source and destination addresses (double NAT).  It may be better to use split DNS with your external DNS names resolving to local IP addresses on the local network.

Comment: This makes perfect sense.. but why is not the same thing also for HTTP?

Comment: @Tom  HTTP can use large transmission windows as there the protocol relatively half-duplex with only one side communicating at a time.  SSH maintains a bi-directional control flow which may not play well with SNAT hair-pinning.  I haven't transferred files and check how catty the conrol flow is.  The protocol data flows are significantly different.